# Duplicates on other sites

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, duplicates

As [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackechange.com) has just reached beta I noticed this question: [Nano syntax highlighting for C# and/or ASP.Net](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2163/nano-syntax-highlighting-for-c-and-or-asp-net) duplicated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454/nano-syntax-highlighting-for-c-and-or-asp-net So how should we handle this as a community? Let it slide despite now there are duplication of efforts?

Comment: What is the opinion of the users of the UNIX and Linux Stack Exchange?

Comment: Haven't asked actually. That would be like - well, hypocrisy! But an interesting idea. I might ask them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to draw a solid line around the UNIX/Linux subset that is "Ubuntu". Clearly in the Ubuntu circle might be questions on the Ubuntu community, Ubuntu-related services (like Ubuntu One), or to Ubuntu-originated work (e.g. themes, indicators). Otherwise the line is very fuzzy.

At this stage it is likely best to take a gentle approach until there is clear picture of the communities developed around the two sites. There will be overlap, but I think that overall the profiles will be slightly different. With a larger body of questions and answers on both sites it should be more clear where a particular question belongs. In my opinion that would be on the site where it's likely to get better answers.

For me, I haven't been able to answer very many questions on this site but I do try to answer some of them. I'm not sure I would be comfortable answering questions on a general site because I'm not at all familiar with UNIX or Linux systems other than Ubuntu.

On the other hand, I don't see any problem with users that have the power casting a vote to close or migrate any question they think is off topic. If there is agreement the other votes will likely join in quickly, and if there is not the question will remain. If the consensus later shifts, then the question can be reopened. (At least that's my understanding of how the Stack Exchange system is supposed to work.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's practical to say no to duplicating content if it means. Most questions here have been answered somewhere else on the internet.

For the purpose of having our own set of answers, a succinct quote or paraphrase of the answer and a link.

If there are exact duplicates on *this* site, post the link to the question as a comment and vote to close the thread.

Comment: I can understand having answered questions on forums - However this is an *exact* duplicate on another stackexchange site. Should we consider that in our scope?

Comment: If it was posted first on another Stack Exchange site then closing seems appropriate.

Comment: @moberly, can you reflect that in your answer?

Answer (score -3):

If a question is not specific to Ubuntu, but it's a general Linux/Unix question, such as one about the `nano` editor, it belongs to Unix&Linux. What would be the point of posting it to AskUbuntu? If there were an AskMint, should anyone post it there too?

Comment: Thing is, Ask Ubuntu gets a lot of users who are new to the Linux word and/or are new to the Stack Exchange network. Those users wouldn't know about the fact that their answer might exist in [unix.se] or that [unix.se] even exists. And telling them to take their question about using a software bundled with Ubuntu elsewhere, is not very good idea.

Comment: @Dan: telling them *gently and respectfully* to take the question to a different site, or migrating it there directly, should be OK, no?